# What is the point of optional selector in jQuery .on() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has an optional selector like this:

```
$("foo").on(events, ["selector"], handler)
```

This code finds "foo" in DOM and filter its descendants with "selector", then bind the event to the filtered result.

I think the above code is completely same as this code without the optional selector

```
 $("foo selector").on(events, handler)
```

This code finds "foo" in DOM, then finds "selector" in descendants of "foo" (the result is same as above code).

---

Real example:

```
$(".class1").on("click" , ".class2", function(){});
```

and

```
$(".class1 .class2").on("click" , function(){});
```

My question is what is the difference between above codes?

If there is not any difference, why jquery has this option (is it redundant)?

Comment: From the jQuery documentation: *When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.*

Comment: @Pointy, I have red that document, but it confirms my station. The result of my examples are completely same.

Comment: @Arashsoft Yes, on static elements, the results will always be the same. You're targeting the same set of elements, the difference is in where the event handler is actually bound. In once case you're binding to elements with class1, and in the other you're binding to elements with class2. In both cases the event handler will only be called if the event was triggered on an element with class2 that is inside an element with class1.

Comment: They're not the same.  Delegated event handling means that you associate the event handler to an element close to the root of the DOM, and it handles events for child elements. It is useful when the DOM may be built incrementally over time, because the event handlers will work for elements that were not in the DOM when the event handler was registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first understand the working of jQuery `.bind()` and `.delegate()` to understand the optional parameter in `.on()`.

`$("#element").bind("click", clickFn)` attaches an event listener to `#element` whereas `$("body").delegate("#element", "click", clickFn)` attaches the event handler to body and will check if the event originated from `#element`, if it did, `clickFn` is executed, else it is ignored.

`$("#element").bind("click", clickFn)` is identically similar to `$("#element").on("click", clickFn)`;

`$("body").delegate("#element", "click", clickFn)` is identically similar to `$("body").on("click", "#element", clickFn)`

In fact, jQuery internally calls `.on()` when `.bind()` and `.delegate()` are triggered.

Answer (score 2):

if i am not wrong:
one event handler for all cells

```
 $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){...});
```

separate event handlers for every td

```
$('table td').on('click', function(){...});
```

Answer (score 2):

With three parameters you will use **"event delegation"**. This technique allow you to avoid two troubles:

1. Keep better memory performance because you are attaching an event to a parent element so you will have only one event valid to a lot of events, for example, you can attach event delegale click to a div with id "my-element" and manage the click for all paragraphs:

   `$("#my-element").on('click', 'p', function(event) {});`
2. If you have events associated on the page (for example, on click on all paragraphs) and you load more paragraphs using ajax and put on html then new elements will not have the previous events associated, for example:

   ```
   // jquery will find all "p" on the DOM
   $("p").on('click', function(event) {
           // click on element p
       });


   // now, if you add more elements p to the DOM, will not have 
   // the previous click event, but with event delegation click event will be available automatically
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies on how you want to target certain element lookup vs target element in a certain expression.

`$(".class1 .class2").on("click" , function(){});` -> This would just invoke click event on elements having classes `class2` inside `class1`

**For example :**

```
$(".class1 .class2").on("click" , function(){
  $(this) // represents elements with class2 inside class1
});
```

`$(".class1").on("click" , ".class2", function(){});` -> This would target the  elements having class `class2` inside `class1` during click event.

**For example :**

```
$(".class1").on("click" , ".class2", function(){
  $(this) // represents elements with class2 inside elements with class1
});
```